# Python Flask AWS S3 EU Central | Bad Request The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

Tags: python, amazon-s3, flask, request

First of all I know there are many similar threads, I red all of them and the S3 Docu (please dont close this thread). The fix is everywhere the same:

Simply change the `sugnature_version` to `v4`, because `eu central` was created after 2014 and does not support `v2` anymore.

I have tried every syntax now and I am still getting the error.

```
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=app.config['MY_AWS_ID'],
    aws_secret_access_key=app.config['MY_AWS_SECRET'],
    region_name='eu-central-1'
)

s3 = session.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))

presigned_post = s3.generate_presigned_post(
Bucket = 'mybucket',
Key = 'videos/' + file_name,
Fields = {"acl": "public-read", "Content-Type": file_type},
Conditions = [
  {"acl": "public-read"},
  {"Content-Type": file_type}
],
ExpiresIn = 3600
)
```

I have tried changing it everywhere. I also downgraded my `boto3` installation to versions `1.6.6` and `1.4.4`, did not work aswell. I upgarded it back to the newest version, which is `boto3==1.7.26`

The Error:

```
InvalidRequest

The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
```

Every thread suggests the same fix, probably it does not work because I use `Python / Flask`. Something has to be done in a different way?

I am trying to upload huge video files via clientside directly to S3, therefore I need to sign the request.

**EDIT**

I thought maybe there is an SSL issue. I am testing everything on localhost and the default option for `use_ssl` is `true`.

I tried to upload this version to the live site (there is SSL enabled). Did not work, still the same error.

I also tried to use `use_ssl = False` on `localhost`, still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the HTML and how I named the input fields. I took an example from an older tutorial, but you have to build your form the way it is explained [here by amazon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html)

I have used every input they provided. I have checked my response, which was generated by my sign_s3 function and pupulated all corresponding fields in the form.

Here is my sign function:

```
# Sign request for direct file upload through client for video
@app.route('/sign_s3/<path:file_name_data>/<path:file_type_data>/<up_type>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
@check_confirmed
def sign_s3(file_name_data, file_type_data, up_type):
    if "localhost" in request.url_root:
        if up_type == "profile_vid":
            file_name = str(current_user.id) + get_random_code(5) + "local-profil-video." + file_name_data.split(".")[-1]
        else:
            file_name = str(current_user.id) + str(randint(1,100)) + "local-post-video-temp." + file_name_data.split(".")[-1]
    else:
        if up_type == "profile_vid":
            file_name = str(current_user.id) + get_random_code(5) + "-profil-video." + file_name_data.split(".")[-1]
        else:
            file_name = str(current_user.id) + str(randint(1,100)) + "-post-video-temp." + file_name_data.split(".")[-1]

    file_type = file_type_data

    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=app.config['MY_AWS_ID'],
        aws_secret_access_key=app.config['MY_AWS_SECRET'],
        region_name='eu-central-1'
    )

    s3 = session.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))

    presigned_post = s3.generate_presigned_post(
    Bucket = 'mybucket',
    Key = 'videos/' + file_name,
    Fields = {"acl": "public-read", "Content-Type": file_type},
    Conditions = [
      {"acl": "public-read"},
      {"Content-Type": file_type}
    ],
    ExpiresIn = 3600
    )

    if up_type == "profile_vid":
        if current_user.profile_video != None:
            delete_file_from_aws("videos/", current_user.profile_video)
        setattr(current_user, "profile_video", file_name)
    else:
        print ('post video has been uploaded, no need to delete or set here')

    db_session.commit()

    return json.dumps({'data': presigned_post, 'url': 'https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/' + 'videos/' + file_name, 'created_file_name' : file_name})
```

I looked at the generated response in the dev console, there I had these values:

[image]

The HTML form I used is here, all the input fields which are uncommented have not been used by me. I simply include them as amazon shows them all in their example:

```
<form id="direct_s3_profile_video_form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <!-- Content-Type:  -->
   <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type">
   <!-- <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-meta-uuid"> --> 
   <!-- <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-server-side-encryption"> -->
   <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Credential">
   <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Algorithm">
   <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Date">                  
   <!-- Tags for File: --> 
   <!-- <input type="hidden"  name="x-amz-meta-tag"> -->
   <input type="hidden" name="Policy">
   <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature">
   <input id="NEW_fileupload_video" type="file" name="file" accept="video/*">                   
   <button type="submit"> Upload </button>
</form>
```

Also note here that the file input must be at the bottom because:

> elements after this will be ignored

In my case the values for the form were dynamically created, so I populated the form with JS:

```
$('#direct_s3_profile_video_form').find('input[name="key"]').val(response_json_data.data.fields['key']);
$('#direct_s3_profile_video_form').find('input[name="acl"]').val(response_json_data.data.fields['acl']);
$('#direct_s3_profile_video_form').find('input[name="Content-Type"]').val(response_json_data.data.fields['Content-Type']);
$('#direct_s3_profile_video_form').find('input[name="X-Amz-Credential"]').val(response_json_data.data.fields['x-amz-credential']);
$('#direct_s3_profile_video_form').find('input[name="X-Amz-Algorithm"]').val(response_json_data.data.fields['x-amz-algorithm']);
$('#direct_s3_profile_video_form').find('input[name="X-Amz-Date"]').val(response_json_data.data.fields['x-amz-date']);
$('#direct_s3_profile_video_form').find('input[name="Policy"]').val(response_json_data.data.fields['policy']);
$('#direct_s3_profile_video_form').find('input[name="X-Amz-Signature"]').val(response_json_data.data.fields['x-amz-signature']);  
$('#direct_s3_profile_video_form').attr('action', 'https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com');
```